# DC Motor stops working for a couple if time at cold start every time

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, robotics, systems-engineering

We have a DC motor that is connected to the track with couplers. Every day at cold start (when it hasn't run for sometime), when we start the motor while moving up (Z-axis) the motor stops (brakes activate). This happens one or two times only at full speed, not at lower speeds. After that, it works perfectly the whole day without stopping (stalling).
We have been trying to figure out the reason and but no luck so far. We know the stop or stall happens once the motor reaches max velocity i.e., after acceleration is complete.
It is a repeatable issue on more than one motor (we have two systems). I am assuming there is something we missed. Anyone has any ideas? Thanks in advance.

DC Stepper motor 8 A. motor torque 4 N m
Max weighs 28 kg which needs to be carried at 1134 mm stroke.
Tracks are belt driven.

Comment: Welcome to engineering SE. What are the specifications of the stepper motor? How are you driving the motor?

Comment: Perhaps sharing the motor's datasheet or a picture of the setup could help a lot. Due to your description, the only thing I could imagine might be something related to the bearing on the guide rail (if that is even present). but that would have nothing to do with the fact that it only happens at max velocity.

Comment: What's the layout of your track like? If it's a repeatable problem it's probably not the motor itself. Could be a minute obstacle on your track that gets pushed back at lower speeds or after higher cycles but provides too much resistance at cold start.

Comment: You say brakes activate. That is an active action which the controller is doing - motors don't brake by themselves. Did you ask the controller what's going on?